# Autocomplete In Jquery does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

*Then I have a list of provinces that recovery from db and turn into json.*
All'autocomplete I serve this file province.php that return a list of all the provinces.
The file does is show all the provinces with the simple query SELECT * FROM provinces.

I was forced to choose this path so as to put this cached result and avoid No database queries only to the choice of the province.

**The real problem is what?**

That autocomplete works in his own way or does see the list of all the provinces province.php extracted from the file, but it is not able to filter the results.

So if I write MILA ... should show only the provinces that boarders with MILA .. because instead always gives me the entire list?

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#province" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'province.php'
    });
  });
</script>
```

The file province.php returns something like this:

> {"0":{"id":"1","label":"Milano","value":"Milano"},"1":{"id":"2","label":"Cagliari","value":"Cagliari"},"2":{"id":"3","label":"Messina","value":"Messina"},"5":{"id":"4","label":"Roma","value":"Roma"},"6":{"id":"5","label":"Venezia","value":"Venezia"}}

As if I do this instead works:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var province = [
      { label: "milano", value: "milano", id: 1 },
      { label: "Cagliari", value: "Cagliari", id: 2 },
      { label: "Messina", value: "Messina", id: 3 },
      { label: "Roma", value: "Roma", id: 4 },
      { label: "Catania", value: "Catania", id: 5 },
      { label: "Venezia", value: "Venezia", id: 6 }
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: province
    });
  });
  </script>
```

why?

Comment: that returned JSON and the one that you write manually are different, have yout tried to return and array instead of an object?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `for..in` to parse your object into the `[]` you need, like this :

```
// The following object masquerades as an array.
var fakeArray = {
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
            "label": "Milano",
            "value": "Milano"
    },
        "1": {
        "id": "2",
            "label": "Cagliari",
            "value": "Cagliari"
    },
        "2": {
        "id": "3",
            "label": "Messina",
            "value": "Messina"
    },
        "5": {
        "id": "4",
            "label": "Roma",
            "value": "Roma"
    },
        "6": {
        "id": "5",
            "label": "Venezia",
            "value": "Venezia"
    }
}

var realArray = [];

for (var i in fakeArray) {
    realArray.push(fakeArray[i]);
}
```

Now `realArray` will contain the data in the form you need :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "label": "Milano",
        "value": "Milano"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "label": "Cagliari",
        "value": "Cagliari"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "label": "Messina",
        "value": "Messina"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "label": "Roma",
        "value": "Roma"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "label": "Venezia",
        "value": "Venezia"
    }
]
```

Now, all you need to do is,

```
$("#test").autocomplete({
    source: realArray
})
```

Assuming `#test` is the id of your text box.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/rNzpg/1/

**Edit :**
If you're data is coming from a `php` file, use `getJSON` to get the data first :

```
$.getJSON('province.php').done(function(result) {
   fakeArray = result ; 

   var realArray = [];

   for (var i in fakeArray) {
        realArray.push(fakeArray[i]);
   }

    $("#test").autocomplete({
      source: realArray
    });  

});
```

**PHP** : To make your looping in code itself, your PHP code must construct an array like this :

```
 var $array = array();
 foreach ($province as $provincia) { 
   array_push($array, $province);
 } 

 echo json_encode($array)
```

Be sure to have this : header('Content-type: application/json');

Then your JS could look very simple :

```
 $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: "province.php"
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello thanks for the reply, but the data comes from province.php not js.

Comment: Ok thank you very much works, but this is the only method? The provinces can not be loaded only when you type the autocomplete?
Or is there no way to do this from php? so why waste resources, I always make a loop in JavaScript when php already did it.

Comment: then you must make the array in php and return it here. else you'll have to use this way.

Comment: File Province:
foreach ($province as $provincia) {
 $array[] = array(
                    'id'    => $provincia['id'],
                    'label' => $provincia['provincia'],
                    'value' => $provincia['provincia']
 );                                                                 
}                                                                        echo json_encode($array)

Comment: sorry, I dont know php :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function() {
    $("#province").autocomplete({
        source : function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('province.php').done(function(result) {
                var regex = new RegExp(request.term, 'i');

                var array = $.map(result, function(item, idx) {
                    if(!regex.test(item.label)){
                        return;
                    }

                    return {
                        label : item.label,
                        value : item.value,
                        id : item.id
                    }
                });
                response(array)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hello thanks for the reply, I tried but it does not work you do not see the autocomplete. Why?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined

Comment: it works, but I do not filter results, that is if I compile a single list does not filter.
:( How can I do?

Comment: you need to filter the data in server, you can pass the entered search term to server as a parameter

Comment: @CarolCasta see the update it sends a parameter `query` to server, you should return the data after filtering

Comment: no I can not do query with the where clause, because unless everything in cache. So I have to be able to read from a static array and make a filter with jquery autocomplete.